# Volume of a function rotated about y=x

Tags: calculus

My friend asked me for help solving this problem out of his calc ab text book, and I wasn't really sure how to do it. The question asks to compute the volume of the solid obtained by rotating a pictured region about the line y=x. The region is $x^{1/4} \leq y \leq 1 $. [region described graphed on desmos.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBuD3.png)
I saw a similar post and followed the instructions in the comments, but got an answer of $\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt 2}$

Any help would be greatly appreciated mostly because its bothering me I don't know how to do this yet lol.

Also sorry for any formatting issues I'm not very familiar with how to format questions correctly on here.

EDITS:
Okay, so here's [the link to the other post that I tried following](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3052413/the-volume-of-solid-of-revolution-rotated-about-the-line-y-x). I attempted the problem again, and came to the final answer of
$\frac{2\pi}{9\sqrt 2}$ [Here's my work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2txR.png)
Still not sure that this is correct.

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question, adding to it *how* you got $\frac\pi{3\sqrt2}$.

Answer (score 1):

A point $(x, y)$ in the region has a distance away from the line $y = x$ given by

$ r = \dfrac{ | y - x | }{\sqrt{2}} $

In the region given, $y \gt x $ , therefore

$ r = \dfrac{y-x}{\sqrt{2}} $

Now you have to find the value of the double integral

$ V = \displaystyle \int_{x = 0 }^ 1 \int_{ y = x^{\frac{1}{4} }}^ 1 (2 \pi r) dy dx $

And this becomes

$ V = \sqrt{2} \pi \displaystyle \int_{x = 0 }^ 1 \int_{ y = x^{\frac{1}{4}} }^1 (y - x)  dy dx$

Integrating with respect to $y$, this gives us

$ V = \sqrt{2} \pi \displaystyle \int_{x = 0 }^ 1 \frac{1}{2}(1 - x^{\frac{1}{2}} ) - x (1 - x^{\frac{1}{4}}) dx $

Integrating now from $x = 0 $ to $x = 1$ , yields

$ V = \sqrt{2} \pi \left( \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{4}{9} \right) = \dfrac{  \sqrt{2} \pi }{9} $

Which is the answer you got.

There's a more involved way to do this computation, through rotation.

If we rotate the region and the axis by $45^\circ$ clockwise, then we can integrate with respect to a single variable.  Our curve is given parametrically as $(t, t^{1/4}) , t \in [0,1] $.  Rotating the region by $45^\circ$ clockwise about the origin, the curve is mapped to

$ (x(t), y(t)) = (f(t), g(t)) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ( t + t^{1/4} , - t + t^{1/4} ) $

To simplify the integration process, we'll find the volume of the solid that is the "core" (i.e. closer to the axis, corresponding to $x \le y \le x^{1/4} $, and at the end we'll just subtract the found volume from the volume of the double cones that are base to base.

The volume here is

$ V' = \pi \displaystyle \int_D y^2 dx = \pi \int_{t=0}^{t = 1} y^2 \dfrac{dx}{dt} dt $

We have $ y^2 = \frac{1}{2} (t^2 + t^{1/2} - 2 t^{5/4} ) $

$ \dfrac{dx}{dt} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (1 + \frac{1}{4} t^{-3/4} ) $

Putting it all together, we get

$V' = \dfrac{\pi}{2 \sqrt{2} } \displaystyle \int_0^1 (t^2 + t^{1/2} - 2 t^{5/4} + \frac{1}{4} t^{5/4} + \frac{1}{4} t^{-1/4} - \frac{1}{2} t^{1/2} ) dt$

$=  \dfrac{\pi}{2 \sqrt{2} } \displaystyle \int_0^1 (t^2 +\frac{1}{2}t^{1/2} - \frac{7}{4} t^{5/4}  + \frac{1}{4} t^{-1/4} ) dt $

$= \dfrac{\pi}{2 \sqrt{2} } \left( \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{7}{9} + \frac{1}{3} \right)$

$= \dfrac{ \pi }{ 9 \sqrt{2}} $

Now the volume of the double cone base to base is

$ V_{Cones} = \dfrac{2\pi}{3} \left( \dfrac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}} \right) = \dfrac{ \pi }{ 3 \sqrt{2} } $

hence the required volume is

$ V = V_{Cones} - V' = \dfrac{ \pi }{ 3 \sqrt{2} } - \dfrac{  \pi }{9 \sqrt{2}} = \pi \sqrt{2} \left( \dfrac{1}{6} - \dfrac{1}{18} \right)$

$= \dfrac{\pi \sqrt{2}}{9} $

Comment: This was asked in a calc 1 textbook, is there another way to do it that doesn't involve double integrals?

Comment: Yes.  There is.  I'll add this to my solution as the second method.

Comment: @lms2234 I've added the second method to my solution.